# Get Sqlite SQL statement from IQueryable in .NET core

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

my .NET Core console app connects to an sqlite db

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19176.6" />

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
   string connectionString = "Data Source=\\mydb.db;";
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
}

var q = dbc.mytable.Select(x => x);
```

How can I get the underlying SQL query used by q ?

If I try `q.ToString()` I get:

> "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MyProj.mytable]"

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your IQueryable instance is as per your example:

```
var q = dbc.mytable.Select(x => x);  // your sample IQueryable object
```

For EntityFramework versions prior to EF Core, this would have worked

```
var sqlQuery = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)q).ToTraceString();
```

and for EF 6, this would have worked

```
var sqlQuery = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)q).ToTraceString();
```

Sorry that I didn't look at the tags of your question earlier which mentions EF core.

In that case I found [this](http://rion.io/2016/10/19/accessing-entity-framework-core-queries-behind-the-scenes-in-asp-net-core/) article which provides few options to achieve the objective if using EF Core.

Comment: I get "The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'"

Comment: edited my answer and added the link of an article which i think is relevant to EF core scenario. Please try that.